# How can i populate a JTable via a dynamic array or ArrayList fwith values from a database

Tags: java, swing

I have 6 columns and a maximum of about 20 rows in the database. I like to make a general program in Java that populates the JTable with these values. I am very much conversant with using dynamic arrays, but not familiar with JTable attributes and model in Swing.

Can anyone guide me here on tho requirement? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the JTable tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)

Comment: You can also use the `ResultSetTableModel` which does all the work for you. Here is an article detailing its usage: http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/java/news/javaex_1000.html. All you have to do is provide an SQL query and a DB-connection

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own table model. See the API documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html

Basically, `getColumnCount()` would return your number of columns, `getRowCount()` the number of rows in your database, `getColumnName(int columnIndex)` some name for every column (the column name from the database or an arbitrary name, maybe from a constant string array). `getColumnClass(int columnIndex)` can, in the simple case, return String.class for every column. Then you have to convert every value to string.

`getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` has to return the value from the database for the given row and column. You should probably pre-load all these values in a 2D array or something like this (but that would be the answer to another question ;) ).

You can ignore the other methods for now, they are for editable tables.

Your code could look something like this:

```
String[][] tableData = readTableDataFromDatabase();
String columnNames = initColumnNames(); //From DB or constants
TableModel model = new DbTableModel(tableData, columnNames);

class DbTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[][] tableData;
    private String[] columnNames;

    public DbTableModel(String[][] tableData, columnNames) {
        this.tableData = tableData;
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return tableData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return tableData.length;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        if(tableData.length == 0)
            return 0;
        return tableData[0].length;
    }
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column]
    }
}
```

This example assumes that you read the data from the database as a 2D array. If you use an O/R-Mapper (like the Java Persistence API - JPA), which I **highly** recommend, you would probably load a list of Entities. Each entity would contain the data for a table row. Anyway, the table model would not change much. Instead of accessing array values, you would get an entity object from the list and call "`get`"-Methods on the Entity.

There's more information in the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Some nice advice, be nice if you can back it up with a simple example. It'd be would also be nice if you could reference the Java 7 API ;)

Comment: Please link to the current Javadoc version.

Comment: I added an example and linked to the recent JavaDoc. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Here's a sample of a List-based read-only TableModel I wrote some time ago:

https://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java

Answer (score 0):

Nice but i hope  readTableDataFromDatabase(); return resultset object